# C# Anonymous Type access from other method

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

i've a ComboBox where is filled using a Collections of Anonymous Type:

```
var results = (from row in data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
               select new { 
                    Id = row.Field<int>("id"),
                    Name = row.Field<string>("Name
               }).Distinct();

myComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

foreach (var n in results)
{
    myComboBox.Items.Add(n);
}
```

Then, in SelectedIndexChanged method of the comboBox, i want to retrieve the Id of the selected item, but i can't access to the "Id" property, in myComboBox.SelectedItem is the selected object.

```
private void myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var x = myComboBox.SelectedItem;

            ¿¿¿ ???
    }  
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you just need the id can you use myCombobox.SelectedValue?

Comment: The *dynamic* keyword is going to get you into trouble.  The members of an anonymous type have *internal* accessibility.  Or in other words, you cannot access them when your UI code is in a separate assembly.  Which is very common, separating the UI from the data model is a worthy pursuit.  Simply don't use an anonymous type here.

Comment: Using anon and/or dynamic types isn't the answer here. What's wrong with your own lightweight type? (Or, for this particular example, [`KeyValuePair<int,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)?)

Comment: Or, use `Tuple<int, string>`, which is more general purpose than `KeyValuePair`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection too.

```
private void myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var x = myComboBox.SelectedItem;
        System.Type type = x.GetType();
        int id = (int)type.GetProperty("Id").GetValue(obj, null);
    }  
}
```

Comment: The typecasting trick is much faster than reflection, though I can't say which of them is more likely to continue to work in future versions of C#/CLR.

Answer (score 9):

Since you use Id as valuemember the Id would be stored as myComboBox.SelectedItem.Value

Answer (score 3):

I read an article this morning that explained exactly this:

http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/10/06/playing-with-anonymous-types-in-c/

The idea is that you need to return a "dynamic" type.

```
dynamic GetAnonymousType()
{
    var person = new { Name = "Filip" };
    return person;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with C# 4.0, then use dynamic keyword, otherwise, define a class which contains id and name instead of using anonymous type, or use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the simplest solution? Create a class called SimpleEntity with three fields: Id, Description and Tag. This class should have a constructor that accept an Object and, using reflection, you get Id and Name and set the two fields. And you alse set the Tag property with the Object. In this way, you just need to populate the combo using this new class and then you get back the original object.
I hope it helps.

Comment: You can avoid reflection if the constructor accepts three parameters (int, string, object)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off using something like a `Tuple<int, string>` here, not an anonymous type, but it is *possible* to do what you want.  Two anonymous types in the same assembly that have the same field names and field types in the same order are internally "folded" into a single type. You can use this to pass anonymous type instances around and, using generic type inference, typecast them at a later date.

<strike>Note that this relies on an internal mechanism in the C# compiler, so there's no guarantee it will continue to work; it works, however, in every current version of C# that has anonymous types.</strike>

Update: This is actually called out explicitly in the C# spec, so this should be completely safe to do:

> Within the same program, two anonymous object initializers that specify a sequence of properties of the same names and types in the same order will produce instances of the same anonymous type

Note also that this only works **within a single assembly** (don't let the spec's reference to a "program" confuse you). To consume anonymous types from another assembly requires reflection (and, IMO, is generally a very bad idea.) However, for data binding scenarios such as yours, it works fine.

```
public object foo; 

public void Create()
{
  this.foo = new { Id = 1, Name = "Melvin" };
}

public void Consume()
{
  var x = new { Id = 0, Name = String.Empty };
  var y = this.Cast(this.foo, x);
}

public T Cast<T> ( object o, T template )
{
  return (T)o;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this answer hasn't gotten more love - I think it's fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic` keyword instead of `var`.